# Need help on css

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a theme that I have applied to my wordpress website.
When one enters the site on a large screen (I think larger than 1200px), it looks all good. The theme is supposed to be responsive. But when you enter the website on a tablet or mobile phone, the logo image is not shown properly. Instead of accessing the site on a tablet or phone, you can just make the window smaller in the browser. I am thinking it has something to do with the css? I need expert view. Thanks for any help you can provide.

I don't know what other info to provide, other than I have bought a theme, and uploaded an image/logo, and that image is not showing properly. I tried writing to the creater, but they said it probably has something to do with the settings. Now I just ran into a dead end, tried everything I could. Any advice is appreciated.

And please, before you start giving me bad votes without any constructive citicsm, please tell what other info you needed, so I can do better the next times to come. I have read the rules, and tried to follow them. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide the minimal code (in this case html and CSS) that allows us to reproduce your problem; linking to your site is pointless, because as soon as the problem is fixed no one in the future can see the problem you had. This makes this question nonsensical at best. Also: down-votes indicate that the question was either not useful or unclear. Following the rules, or trying to, doesn't make your question useful, or clear.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try to remember it in any other case. But it's just that in this particular case, it's impossible to know what code to add here. Like I mentioned, I didn't know where the problem was, so I would have to add the entire css, which is probably at least 500 lines of code. No one would want to examine that I think. So having the problem visually is more helpful in my case. But you are right, once the page is down, this topic is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have access to your editor, you will need to go into your style.css and add:

```
header {background-size:contain;}
header .container {min-height:240px;}
```

That will fix your mobile/tablet issues, however the above code will break the header on laptop/desktop so you will also need to add the below media query:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
   header {background-size:initial;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add 
height: 366px;

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
    height: 366px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
    height: 366px;
  }
}
```

In short add height to the div box using media query